# on submitting the form ,it is not validated but gets refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">




function isUpperCase(str) {
return str === str.toUpperCase();
}

function validate()
{
    var flag=0;
    var x=document.getElementById("f").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("l").value;
    var w=document.getElementById("c").value;
    var p=document.getElementById("o").value;
   //the first name should be all capital and less than 20 characters
    if(x.length>20 || x=="" || isUpperCase(x)==false)
    {
        flag=1;
document.getElementById("f").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";  
    }
     //the last name should be less than 15 characters and all capital
    if(y.length>15 || y=="" || isUpperCase(y)==false)
    {
        flag=1;
document.getElementById("l").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";          
    }
    //the customer number length should be 5
    if(w=="" || w.length!=5 )
    {
        flag=1;
    document.getElementById("c").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";          
    }
    //order num length should be 5,first character should be 'p' and next three should be numbers.
    if(p.length!=5 || p.charAt(0)!='p' || isNaN(p.substr(1,3)))
    {
        flag=1;
     document.getElementById("o").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";     
    }
    if(flag==1)
        alert("check the colored boxes");
    return flag;

}

</script>
<form name="myform" onsubmit=" return validate()" action="" method="post">
    first name:<input id="f" type="text" name="first"><br>
    last name:<input id="l" type="text" name="last"><br>
    customer no:<input id="c" type="text" name="customer_num"><br>
    order no:<input id="o" type="text" name="order_num"><br>
    date:<input id="d" type="date" name="date"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I 'm new to javascript and I can't find anything wrong with the function validate.
the function validate checks for the constraints in the form inputs and if the conditions are not met the background color of the input is changed and at the end an alert pops out asking to check the colored boxes.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: the form is not getting validated.it just gets refreshed on submitting

Comment: your flag is `0`/`1` - why don't you use `boolean` for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are returning either `1` or `0`

if you want to prevent form sending you have to return `false`

Comment: thank you.That was the problem.The form kept on submitting even if it was not validated.Using boolean instead of 1 and 0 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that in your first two if statements you are using an assignment operator `=` as opposed to a comparative operator `==`. Try Changing

```
if(x.length>20 || x="" || isUpperCase(x)==false)
```

to

```
if(x.length>20 || x=="" || isUpperCase(x)==false)
```

and the same with the `y` if statement.

Comment: yes,now the alert pops up saying check the colored boxes but still the color does not change.The color only changes for a brief moment and then it gets refreshed

Comment: I think it because the function returns flag so then refresh your page and your css file try to remove "return flag" at the end of your function

Answer (score 0):

Hi please change your action to point to you function. Also you forgot one '=' in your code

```js
 if(y.length>15 || y=="" || isUpperCase(y)==false)
```

. It will fix the issue.

```html
<form name="myform" action="javascript:validate();">
    first name:<input id="f" type="text" name="first"><br>
    last name:<input id="l" type="text" name="last"><br>
    customer no:<input id="c" type="text" name="customer_num"><br>
    order no:<input id="o" type="text" name="order_num"><br>
    date:<input id="d" type="date" name="date"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Final code will be like

```js
function isUpperCase(str) {
return str === str.toUpperCase();
}

function validate(e)
{
    var flag=0;
    var x=document.getElementById("f").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("l").value;
    var w=document.getElementById("c").value;
    var p=document.getElementById("o").value;
   //the first name should be all capital and less than 20 characters
    if(x.length>20 || x=="" || isUpperCase(x)==false)
    {
        flag=1;
document.getElementById("f").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";  
    }
     //the last name should be less than 15 characters and all capital
    if(y.length>15 || y=="" || isUpperCase(y)==false)
    {
        flag=1;
document.getElementById("l").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";          
    }
    //the customer number length should be 5
    if(w=="" || w.length!=5 )
    {
        flag=1;
    document.getElementById("c").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";          
    }
    //order num length should be 5,first character should be 'p' and next three should be numbers.
    if(p.length!=5 || p.charAt(0)!='p' || isNaN(p.substr(1,3)))
    {
        flag=1;
     document.getElementById("o").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";     
    }
    if(flag==1)
        alert("check the colored boxes");
    return flag;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="javascript:validate();">
    first name:<input id="f" type="text" name="first"><br>
    last name:<input id="l" type="text" name="last"><br>
    customer no:<input id="c" type="text" name="customer_num"><br>
    order no:<input id="o" type="text" name="order_num"><br>
    date:<input id="d" type="date" name="date"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```